# Robotframework treats variables passed from python class as 'None'

Tags: python, robotframework

i have a python class  **Wiresharking.py**

```
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,PIPE,STDOUT
import time
import subprocess
import datetime
import os
#import envSI

class Wiresharking:

        """Wireshark Server subclass"""

        def __init__(self,**kwargs):

                self.filters=''
                self.window_ip = kwargs.get('ip')
                print type(self.window_ip)
                self.window_user= kwargs.get('username')
                self.window_password= kwargs.get('password')
                self.dest_path= kwargs.get('Target_path')
                self.interface= kwargs.get('interface')
                self.terminal='cmd'
                self.home=kwargs.get('Home_path')


        def test(self):
            print 'hi'
            return self.window_ip
```

i can call it from another python file (**env.py**) like below

```
SERVER_01 = Wiresharking(
        name='WIRESHARK_ENV91',
        ip='192.168.1.16',
        username=r'INTRA\pmmm',   #always prepend r , before giving your username and password
        password='jan@2018',
        prompt='$ ',
        autostart=False,
        unzip_capture=True,
        filter='',
        #interface=['ens2f0'],
        interface='Ethernet',
        Target_path=r'D:\Users\pankaj-m\Desktop\Test'
        )

print SERVER_01.test()
```

output :

```
<type 'str'>
hi
192.168.1.16
```

however , the problem arises when i use **env.py** file as --variable file with robotframework

command

```
pybot -V env.py Check.robot
```

**Check.robot** file is below

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Wiresharking.py
*** Test Cases ***
Test
    check
*** Keywords ***
check
    ${abc} =    test
    log    ${abc}
```

the output i here getting is **'None'**

```
16:13:37.279 INFO None
```

can anyone point out what wrong i am doing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `env.py` defines a single variable named `${SERVER_01}`. However, `Check.robot` never uses that variable.

`Check.robot` imports `Wiresharking.py` without passing any arguments. That causes its `self.window_ip` to be `None`, and thus the keyword returns `None`.

If you want to see the values from `env.py`, you need to look at the `${SERVER_01}` variable. For example:

```
log  ${SERVER_01.window_ip}
```

Comment: how will i pass **kwargs values from robot to __init__

Comment: i have posted an answer , if you can point out anyother way to pass  **kwargs , it would be great

Answer (score 0):

This is the way i was able to pass **kwargs  and able to resolve error .

I am still looking for a cleaner way to pass **kwargs

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Wiresharking.py   ip=${SERVER_01.window_ip}    username=${SERVER_01.window_user}    password=${SERVER_01.window_password}    Target_path=${SERVER_01.dest_path}    interface=${SERVER_01.interface}    Home_path=${SERVER_01.home}  WITH NAME    Mylib

*** Variables ***
${window_ip }
#&{names} =  Create Dictionary   0=First Name    2=Email
*** Test Cases ***
Test
    check
*** Keywords ***
check
    ${abc} =    test
    log    ${abc}
```

Output

```
INFO 192.168.1.16
```